# What is the best way to refactor out "temporal dependence" of instance methods?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

For example, suppose in a view class we need to instantiate some UI components and then populate the fields. Something like:

```
var View = function() {
  this._initUI();
  this._populateFields();
};

View.prototype = {
  _initUI: function() {
    this.textField = new TextField();
    this.comboBox = new Combobox();
  },

  _populateFields: function() {
    this.textField.setText('foo');
    this.comboBox.setVal('bar');
  }
};
```

This doesn't quite smell right, as you must call `_initUI` before `_populateFields`, and it's pretty hidden that `_initUI` will be creating some instance variables that will later be used by `_populateFields`.

What's your opinion of a better way of doing this?

Comment: Fix the prototype to do the initialization? Throw an exception if initUI hasn't been called? There are any number of ways this *could* be done.

Comment: What do you mean by fix the prototype to do the initialization? You mean fix the constructor? As in, basically pull `_initUI` directly into the constructor? If so, this may not be a great option when you need to initialize a non-trivial UI view.

Comment: You don't need to pull the *code* in, just the call to init. In any case, there are a ton of ways to ensure an object is initialized properly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding with definite answers. This is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com, or possibly programmers.stackexchange.com, which is for discussions about high-level design concepts and best practices.

Comment: @AdiInbar That's a good point, this is more of a best-practices question and not "how do I do this" question. Thanks, will re-post it there.